# I can't set <div> background color by button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm learning javascript and as a practice I made a poor version of Paint ( without Canvas ). Its very simple project. I created a div as a brush and when I painting new divs are created. Unfortunatelly, buttons to change brush color ( of div) don't works. I am very curious to know where I made a mistake :)

Here's my code:

```js
let clicked = false;
const dane = function(e) {
  if (clicked == false) return;

  var x = e.clientX;
  var y = e.clientY;
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.style.top = y + "px";
  div.style.left = x + "px";
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}

const klik = function(e) {
  var x = e.clientX;
  var y = e.clientY;
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.style.top = y + "px";
  div.style.left = x + "px";
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}

const tak = function() {
  clicked = true;
}

const nie = function() {
  clicked = false;
}


function paint() {
  document.body.addEventListener("mousemove", dane);
  document.body.addEventListener("mousedown", tak);
  document.body.addEventListener("mouseup", nie);
  document.body.addEventListener("click", klik);
}

// change color below
let color = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

color.blue = function() {
  this.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}

color.red = function() {
  this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

color.green = function() {
  this.style.backgroundColor = "green";
}

window.onload = paint;
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
}

div {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
}

#btnblue {
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: aqua;
  z-index: 100;
}

#btnred {
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 100;
}

#btngreen {
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 275px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: chartreuse;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<button id="btnblue" onclick="blue();"></button>

<button id="btnred" onclick="red();"></button>

<button id="btngreen" onclick="green();"></button>
```

Comment: What is `color.blue = function() {
  this.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}` meant to do? You are adding a `blue` property to an HTML Collection, and never call it.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to call the functions like `blue()` when you assigned them to `color.blue()`, plus you are setting the background color of the wrong object anyways.

<s>`let color = document.getElementsByTagName("div");` grabs all of the `div`s that exist in your document at the time you call it. You then add functions to this collection for the different colors. Then, when you click, you add new `div`s that were not a part of that collection, so they don't have those functions.</s> (comments showed that this is wrong)

What you want to do is just have a variable with the color that you want that changes when you click the buttons, and when you add a new `div`, just set its background color at that time.

```js
let clicked = false;
const dane = function(e) {
  if (clicked == false) return;

  var x = e.clientX;
  var y = e.clientY;
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.style.top = y + "px";
  div.style.left = x + "px";
  div.style.backgroundColor = color;
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}

const klik = function(e) {
  var x = e.clientX;
  var y = e.clientY;
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.style.top = y + "px";
  div.style.left = x + "px";
  div.style.backgroundColor = color;
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}

const tak = function() {
  clicked = true;
}

const nie = function() {
  clicked = false;
}


function paint() {
  document.body.addEventListener("mousemove", dane);
  document.body.addEventListener("mousedown", tak);
  document.body.addEventListener("mouseup", nie);
  document.body.addEventListener("click", klik);
}

// change color below
let color = "aqua";

blue = function() {
  color = "aqua";
}

red = function() {
  color = "red";
}

green = function() {
  color = "chartreuse";
}

window.onload = paint;
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
}

div {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
}

#btnblue {
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: aqua;
  z-index: 100;
}

#btnred {
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 100;
}

#btngreen {
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 275px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: chartreuse;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<button id="btnblue" onclick="blue();"></button>

<button id="btnred" onclick="red();"></button>

<button id="btngreen" onclick="green();"></button>
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` gets a `HTMLCollection` which is *live* (in contrast to the `NodeList` `querySelectorAll` gets you). That means any new DIV in the DOM immediately is part of the collection, as well as any DIV being removed it removed from the collection, too.

Comment: @connexo wow, I didn't know that. I just tested it, and you are correct, it does updated with the new `div`s.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very good at this, but I see multiple problems.

- `onclick="blue();"` will not work because there is no function `blue()` exists
- Function `color.blue()` does exist, but since it declared with `let` word it will be not accesible in `window` space, where `onClick` even will look for it
- `this.style.backgroundColor` will not work since `this` equals to `color` which equals to `document.getElementsByTagName("div")` which returns `HTMLCollection` which has its own function `.item()` to get items
- Where is that `div` located anyway? I don't see it in your HTML.

So here is fixed version https://jsfiddle.net/eqpkn153/1/
I did not changed or looked at your other code so no idea what happens there, but button do work now. It changes background of text that I made, not sure what your initial idea was but you can do it yourself.
What I did is:

- Declared `color` in `window.color`
- Added `h1` text with id `message`
- `color` is not equals to `document.getElementById("message")`
- Had to move `paint()` call from `onload="paint();"` to end of js file since jsfiddle.net will not work that way I think. Its just because of jsfilddle.net so you can keep your `paint()` in `onload`

Comment: this is not working. You have to be able to paint in black area with mouse clicks, with previous chosen color